# After adding the line "from qgis.core import QgsApplication", the exe application does not work

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqgis

I am testing a simple PyQgis application. When I add the line "from qgis.core import QgsApplication" and make an exe via pyinstaller, the application crashes with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "qgis\core\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtPositioning'
```

```
import sys

from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
**from qgis.core import QgsApplication**



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Mapová prezeračka ---  Pebieha načítanie dát ...")
        self.init_gui()
        self.show()

    def init_gui(self):
        self.formular = QWidget()
        layoutFormulara = QHBoxLayout()
        self.formular.setLayout(layoutFormulara)
        boxLayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        boxLayout2 = QHBoxLayout()

        layoutFormulara.addStretch()
        layoutFormulara.addLayout(boxLayout1)
        layoutFormulara.addLayout(boxLayout2)
        layoutFormulara.addStretch()

        self.label1 = QLabel("Hello")
        boxLayout1.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.formular)


def main():
    # vytvoriť hlavné okno
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()

    # Spustiť aplikáciu
    try:
        retval = app.exec_()
        # Ukončiť aplikáciu
        sys.exit(retval)  # toto vždy vyvolá SystemExit
    except SystemExit:
        print("sys.exit() fungovalo podľa očakávania")
    except:
        print("Niečo sa strašne pokazilo")  # bola vznesená iná výnimka


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
```

I looked for many answers on the Internet but I couldn't find anything.

I've read the pyinstaller manual, I'm just new to this. I am sending a TestEXE.spec file.

```
import os
block_cipher = None
workdir = os.getenv('VIEWER_DIR')
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=[workdir],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[(os.path.join(workdir,'testdata/*'),'testdata'),
                (os.path.join(workdir,'qgis_plugins/*'),'qgis_plugins'),
                (os.path.join(workdir,'graphics/*'),'graphics'),],
         hiddenimports=['qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets','qgis.core.QgsApplication']
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
         win_private_assemblies=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='TestEXE',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False ,
          icon='graphics/airports.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='TestEXE')
```

Comment: Are you saying that the error only happens when running the compiled binary? Then it means that the builder is not able to detect that it needs that library, you have to add that to the list of modules that must be bundled. Unfortunately, you didn't say what building tool you're using, so we cannot help you about that.

Comment: I using Python  Interpreter C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\python.exe and QGis 3.22 and IDE  Pycharm 2022.2.2

Comment: When I comment out the line "from qgis.core import QgsApplication" the application window starts normally after creating the EXE. I have a larger application, just this small test, I'm trying pyinstaller.

Comment: So, why are you adding that line? Did you read the pyinstaller documentation about including external libraries?

Comment: I have to add that line there because then there will be commands from the PyQgis libraries.

Comment: I have also tried to bundle a simple standalone application based on qgis/pyqgis and got the same error. After adding the missed module (and some more) to the list 'hiddenimport' everything worked: hiddenimports=['pkgutil', 'PyQt5.QtPositioning', 'PyQt5.QtPrintSupport', 'PyQt5.QtSql', 'PyQt5.QtNetwork', 'PyQt5.QtXml']
Maybe this workaround brings you a little bit closer to the solution.

In my case I get then an error on using a class from the 'qgis.gui' module (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76262177/packing-qgis-standalone-application-with-qgis-gui)